# Error SpringBoot/Data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

i'm trying to create a table in my database using Spring Boot but i've have this problem :

[ConsoleError.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgIJo.png)

here is 
Application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

and the Class that i'm using:

```
@Entity
public class Personnel{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(name="NOM")
    private String nom;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
    public Personnel(int id, String nom) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nom = nom;
    }
    public Personnel() {
        super();
    }
}
```

pom.xml (dependencies):

[Pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhqjZ.png)

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Can you share pom.xml and full error stack trace?

Comment: I just add it . Thank you for helping

Comment: please add it as text instead of an image.

Comment: i think it can't found application.properties file

Comment: Please add the console output as text. The image does not cover the whole stack trace. It is always a good idea to post text instead of an image when it comes to console output.

Comment: I solved the problem it was a "space" character added after :spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Comment: Cheers guys ! :)

Answer (score 0):

it can't be found properties file that has hibernate config

Comment: This is absolutly wrong -> Spring Data Jpa provides all your dependencies